# Python - %n.nf format

Tags: python

I'd like to understand the first argument `%n` for the format command `%n.nf`.

IE:

```
print("number is %1.3f" %(1.1000000000))

number is 1.100
```

Ok, I've understand the "3f" is the total of total of digits after decimal point.

but what about the fist argument?

another example:

```
print("number is %3.3f" %(1111.1000000000))

number is 1111.100
```

Argument say 3, but return 4 digits.

or

```
print("number is %10.3f" %(1111.1000000000))

number is   1111.100
```

Even saying 10, not fill with 0.

Comment: `"  1111.100"` _is_ ten characters long. If you want zero-padding that's a _leading_ `0`, `%010.03f`. Frankly digging into `%` (["old"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)) formatting is not worthwhile given the number of better string formatting methods in Python.

Comment: If you want a leading `0` you put that in the format.  Like `%010.3f`.

Comment: You may want to look at this article on printf-style format strings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in `%n.nf` is the minimum field width. It doesn't appear to do anything in your first example (`%1.3f`) because the output is already wider than the minimum specified.

It left-pads with spaces by default, so your second example does work. Just add a leading `0` to get it to pad with zeroes instead of spaces.

```
>>> print("number is %010.3f" %(1111.1000000000))
number is 001111.100
```

See [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) for more details. (As mentioned in the comments, this is the *old* style of string formatting. Ctrl-F on that page to see newer methods.)